# The RelativeLayout ignores the above-rule when a view is added programmatically. How to fix this error?

Tags: java, android

Here is the code snippet:

```
//The view is created manually
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
myListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_lv_layout, null, false);

... //the ListView is prepared (that part of my program works)

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams myListViewParams = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);

myListViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.button_at_the_bottom_of_the_relative_layout);

//the listView is added here, but it is not above the button, but in the upper
//left corner of the screen (the above-rule is simply ignored) 
myRelativeLayout.addView(myListView, myListViewParams);
```

(But the rule `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT` does work here)

In the file `my_lv_layout.xml` are no rules defined except the width and height attributes.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: not getting your actual problem

Comment: R.id.button_at_the_bottom_of_the_relative_layout is the first level of RelativeLayout??? if this is not, the Rule will not apply.

Comment: Oh, how embarassing. Yes, the button is in a LinearLayout, which I have completely forgotten when I wrote that code. I'll give you the tick when you make an answer out of your comment.